# email verification in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.3

I want to check if the user provided email is valid. In order to do that I've modified the registers user file's register method. Here is my code

```
 public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        Mail::to($request->email)->send(new RegistrationConfirmationMail($request->email));
        if( count(Mail::failures()) > 0 ) {
            return redirect('/register')
                ->withInput($request->only('email','name','address','district','gender','mobile'))
                ->withErrors(['invalid_email', 'Your email does not exist. Provide another email']);

        }

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
        $this->registered($user);
        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

But this code doesn't redirect me to the register page instead it registers user and logged in him. How to solve this?

Comment: What mail driver do you use?

Comment: SMTP mail driver

Comment: You're expecting if the user inputs a not existing email address to have the mailer daemon of the domain to return failure?

Comment: yes and redirect to the link

Comment: This failures might come with a delay, so at the check you have the might be 0. Why not make simple confirmation link sent to the user which when clicked would mark his email in the users table as confirmed?